# Migrating Print Servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, print-server

Migrating Windows 2003 print server to Windows 2008 R2 print server.  I have exported/imported the printers from old server to new.  For the printers that wouldn't import I manually added them and gave them the same name that they have on the old server.

Right now I have left the "List in the directory" checkbox unchecked on the new server for each printer.  My plan is to turn off the old server and rename/re-ip the new server to match the old server.

Do I then have to go back and check "List in the Directory" for each printer on the new server?  Is there anything else that needs to be done.  Will users notice anything or will it be seamless?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the List in the Directory feature, although that would depend on your implementation.  Most people know where their printers are, or have them assigned through logon scripts or group policy.

On print servers with a large number of printers, turning off the List feature can help print server startup performance, as it may require several minutes to publish all of those printers in the Directory.  You can observe how long it takes as it registers the publish events in the event log.

Comment: Do you see any problem with renaming/re-ip the new server to match the old server?  As long as the printers have the same share names the transition should be transparent to the user and I shouldn't have to do anything on the client side right?

Comment: It should not be a problem.

Comment: Is anything required on the client end if the print server name changes?  Print queues will remain the same but the print server name is different.  Is the change transparent to the user?

Comment: Should work fine if you create a CNAME for the old server name that points to the new server, and follow this:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/04/23/unable-to-connect-to-a-printer-using-a-cname-record.aspx